# How do I indicate ManyToMany relationship in Django models when both are primary keys?

Tags: django, erd, manytomanyfield

I'm creating Django models and I'm having an issue designating a ManyToMany relationship so that a join table is created in the database. The two models I'm trying to join look like this:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio_information = models.ForeignKey(Bio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Host, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

They need to join on the primary keys, so that I end up with a join table that looks like this with the table name host_team:

```
id int [PK]
host_id int 
team_id int
```

Since you don't include the ID when creating models, how do I designate the MtoM relationship and get django to create the join table?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use join with M2M relationship.

Intead you use `prefetch_related`. It will make additinal query and store result in cache.

In this case your code will look like this:

```
queryset = Team.objects.all().prefetch_related("creator")
```

You can read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related